Is it possible to import a logs from a task in a Cloud Composer?
Currently, we are trying to create an On-Demand Composer in GCP. However, when we recreate the environment, the task logs are not included. How can we Export task logs to our On-Demand Composer and Import it to the recreated environment
We tried to find airflow level logging imports but we're hopeless
